# Discord.JS Bot request npm getting json elements

Tags: javascript, request, discord.js

So I've been trying to call this one website for a json of event data and I can't quite figure out how to get the first chunk of data in the json. This is the website https://api.tftech.de/Event/ I'm only trying to pull this data and then make each one of the values into a variable. `[{"name": "Spooky Event","start": "2020-07-27T02:35:00-05:00","end": "2020-07-27T03:35:00-05:00","priority": "HIGH","color": "ff9800","intervalInMinutes": 7440}]` Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: I want to send a message to a discord channel.

Comment: With what data? What do you have, what do you want to do and where are you stuck? Your question is not telling me much

Comment: The data coming from the website I linked. I don't quite understand how to get the values from the JSON. I've tried stuff like this ```request("https://api.tftech.de/Event/-5", (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        client.channels.cache.get("735404478064230421").send(body[0]["name"]);
    });```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use axios to make requests,
Here is the code block with the results put into variables

```js
var axios = require("axios")

axios.get("https://api.tftech.de/Event/").then(data => {
    var name = data.data[0].name;
    var start = data.data[0].start;
    var end = data.data[0].end;
    var priority = data.data[0].priority;
    var color = data.data[0].color;
    var intervalInMinutes = data.data[0].intervalInMinutes;
})
```